# Downloading a YouTube clip at 1080p from a list of links

Tags: python, download, youtube, youtube-dl, pytube

**Problem Statement**: Downloading a certain clip of a YouTube video at 1080p from a list of YouTube links

So I tried the `PyTube` library but it doesn't seem to support downloading a certain segment of the video.
There has been a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56017234/how-to-download-a-clip-of-an-youtube-video-with-pytube) about the same, and the answer to that supports post-processing in the video to clip it out, but I want to download only that specific clip and not the entire video. Although I am looking for an option that supports downloading multiple videos from a set of links.
Below is the code I used for the same.

```
import time
import pytube
import os
from pytube import YouTube

YouTubeIDs = ['QC8iQqtG0hg']
StartSeg = [2]
EndSeg = [3]

for i in range(len(YouTubeIDs)):
  print(f'Downloading Video {i} with ID {YouTubeIDs[i]}')
  ID = YouTubeIDs[i]
  StartSegment = StartSeg[i]
  EndSegment = EndSeg[i]
  YTLink = f'https://www.youtube.com/embed/{ID}?start={StartSegment}&end={EndSegment}'
  print(f'Link to the YouTube Video - {YTLink}')
  time.sleep(2)
  yt = YouTube(YTLink)
  yt.streams.filter(res="720p").first().download()
  os.rename(yt.streams.filter(res="720p").first().download(), f'YouTube_{i}.mp4')
  print(f'Finished Downloading Video {i}, renamed as YouTube_{i}.mp4')
```

Another approach was tried using `youtube-dl`, but it didn't work because the downloaded video was of 0 KBs. I also tried in a python environment even after the os import, but it gave the same error and I'd very much prefer a Python implementation and not use the bash script unless very necessary.

```
%%bash

ffmpeg $(youtube-dl -g 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnW5EjwtE2U' | sed "s/.*/-ss 10 -i &/") -t 60 -c copy test3.mp4
```

> Sidenote: The idea is to be able to download a specific segment (of about 5-6 seconds) of YouTube video from a CSV file of approximately 2.6 million links. The CSV file contains columns like ['YouTube ID', 'start segment', 'end segment']

Would be grateful to get help in the same.
Please let me know if I need to clarify it more.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it didn't work"?

Comment: But this code works for me. I can download all video.

Comment: @JuanCamiloRiveraPalacio What I meant when I said it doesn't work is that it doesn't download the segmented clip of the video.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, the code works, but I want it to work in a python environment since it is a bash script. To try that, I used `import os` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I have something different for you but i think it will help you!
pip install pytube

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n06H7OcPd-g")
yt = yt.get('mp4', '720p')
yt.download('/path/to/download/directory')
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but can you please check the question again and let me know if I need to clarify it further?

Answer (score 0):

This my version of using `youtube-dl` not sure if it will work in your context and it is done without the use of a batch script.

```
def get_youtube_video(url):
    ydl_opts = {'cachedir': False}

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
```